# I am trying to have a table row open in a new tab using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a table for downloading files on my page and this is the code i have:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).data("href", "_blank");
    });
});
</script>
```

It currently does not open in a new tab. This is for opening a .pdf, so I want it to open said pdf in a new tab. Anyone?

edit: this is the html code

```
<table class="tftable" border="0">
<tr><th>Filer for nedlastning</th></tr>
<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="/s/Profilmanual-april-2018.pdf"><td>Profilmanual</td><td>April 2018</td><td>3,98 MB</td><td>PDF</td>
<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="/s/Logofiler.zip"><td>Logofiler</td><td>April 2018</td><td>7,02 MB</td><td>ZIP</td>
<tr class="hide"><td>Fonter</td><td>April 2018</td><td>X MB</td><td>ZIP</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `target` attribute (instead of doing whatever you're doing with the `href`) on a dynamically inserted `<a>` tag:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").each(function(index) {
        var href = $(this).attr("data-href");
        $(this).children().each(function(index) {
            $(this).html('<a href="' +  href + '" target="_blank">' + $(this).html() +  '</a>');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tftable" border="0">
<tr><th>Filer for nedlastning</th></tr>
<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="/s/Profilmanual-april-2018.pdf"><td>Profilmanual</td><td>April 2018</td><td>3,98 MB</td><td>PDF</td>
<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="/s/Logofiler.zip"><td>Logofiler</td><td>April 2018</td><td>7,02 MB</td><td>ZIP</td>
<tr class="hide"><td>Fonter</td><td>April 2018</td><td>X MB</td><td>ZIP</td>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you can use the `window.open` function:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.open($(this).attr("data-href"), "_blank");
    });
});
```

```css
.clickable-row:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tftable" border="0">
<tr><th>Filer for nedlastning</th></tr>
<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="/s/Profilmanual-april-2018.pdf"><td>Profilmanual</td><td>April 2018</td><td>3,98 MB</td><td>PDF</td>
<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="/s/Logofiler.zip"><td>Logofiler</td><td>April 2018</td><td>7,02 MB</td><td>ZIP</td>
<tr class="hide"><td>Fonter</td><td>April 2018</td><td>X MB</td><td>ZIP</td>
</table>
```

This doesn't seem to work in the Stack Snippet for some reason.

Comment: Shouldn't it refer to `href`somewhere in the code? So it knows where to go.

Comment: @Adee It does. See the runnable Stack Snippet.

Comment: I am sorry for being such a newbie, but now when you click the row nothing happens. Am I missing something? One of the key differences is you use the `.each` function where i have used `.click` .

Comment: @Adee I've made it so you have to click the content, by inserting a `<a>` element that the content is contained within. This has different behaviour to what you've got. I'll add an alternative version.

Comment: Thanks alot, the alternative version using `window.open` function made it work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<script>
var link = whatever ur link is;
window.open(link, '_blank');
</script>
```

Comment: This won't work, since `this` is meaningless outside a function.

Comment: i just suggested window.open , it seems u want me to write the whole syntax of your problem

Comment: You should probably make your answer clearer, since even inside an event handler this won't work; there's no `href` in the provided example.

Comment: is my edit understandable now or should i do any further

Comment: I think it works now (obviously with the correct link substituted in).